# Help! I want to remove Windows EFI Boot Entry, but can’t

Tags: terminal, bootcamp, disk-utility, windows, catalina

I have used the following codes in terminal: [image: terminal]

And here is what’s inside the volume: [image: EFI]

Couldn’t find Microsoft and here are the partitions in disk utility: [image: diskutil]

I honestly don’t know what to do next... Thank you so much in advance.

### Update 1

Done as u asked sir.

[image]

I don’t know much about these complicated stuff btw, i need u to tell me what to do, i just want to be able to install windows again on my macbook.

Comment: Most users use `sudo diskutil mount disk0s1` and `diskutil unmount disk0s1` to mount and unmount the EFI partition. After mounting, try posting the output from `sudo ls -l /Volumes/EFI` and `sudo ls -l /Volumes/EFI/EFI` to your question.

Comment: Done as u asked sir.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you have two files named EFI. I am not sure how there can be two, but neither appears to be a directory (folder). This may prevent the creation of a EFI folder which could prevent the installation of any UEFI booting operation systems which use the EFI partition to boot.

I suppose since the volume seems to be corrupted, I would just reformat the the volume. The commands are given below. The first command can be skipped, if the volume is not mounted.

```
diskutil unmount /dev/disk0s1
sudo newfs_msdos -F 32 -v EFI /dev/rdisk0s1
```

Of course, you should backup all important data before reformatting.

Comment: I've read that this EFI volume has really important info, so should it be replaced or anything to be done after formatting it.

Comment: Also it used to take like a min to boot macOS after entering password, now it takes like 10 mins, does it have anything to do with this?

Comment: You can check to make sure macOS is the startup disk under the System Preferences application. The macOS operating system differs from Windows and Linux in that macOS does not use the EFI partition to boot the computer. Being that the EFI partition was corrupted, it is also possible the macOS partition was also corrupted. If existing damage caused the EFI and macOS partitions to overlap, then reformatting may have caused damage to macOS. If the macOS continues to take 10 minutes to boot, you may consider reinstalling macOS.